# jquery Autocomplete source php htaccess issue

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, autocomplete

I am in the middle of making a CMS as a project.

I want to be able to search a user and it autocomplete with results from a database.

I have got this working on a single page.

But my CMS doesnt seem to want to allow it to work.

The structure I am using is:
admin
-index.php
 -pages
  -moduals.php
pages
 -pages
  -page.php
index.php

in the admin and main index files I have setup an include system.

so if you goto domain.tld/admin/user
it will actually take you to admin/index.php?page=user

the htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ admin/?page=$1&task=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ admin/?page=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/\.]+)/?$ admin/?page=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/ admin/index.php
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=profile&name=$1
RewriteRule ^hardware/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=hardware&name=$1
RewriteRule ^activate/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=activate&akey=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&title=$3


<Files ~ "^\.ht">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy All
</Files>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Compress HTML, plain text, CSS and JavaScript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript

    # Avoid problems in problematic browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 weeks"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 weeks"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 weeks"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 weeks"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2 weeks"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 weeks"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 weeks"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 2 weeks"
</IfModule>
```

the code for the page which I am using the autocomplete file is:

```
    <form action='' method='post'>
        <p><label>username:</label><input type='text' name='username' value='' class='auto'></p>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "jquser.php",
        minLength: 2
    });                

});
</script>
```

the file jquser.php is in the same file as that which is teams.php

The jquser.php file looks like this:

```
<?
define('DB_SERVER', 'XXXXX');
define('DB_USER', 'XXXXX');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXX');
define('DB_NAME', 'XXXX');


if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['username'];
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}

?>
```

Now if i delete the htaccess file it works, it just doesnt work with the htaccess file, I guess its the rewrite rule.

Can someone help me, its probably simple but for some reason my simpleton brain cant handle it.

I am sorry for the long post I wanted to give as much information as possible.

Thanks in advance for your help.